# Is vscode.dev open source? What is different between monaco-editor and vscode.dev

Tags: visual-studio-code, monaco-editor, codesandbox

I wanna create a website similar to https://codesandbox.io, as I see (thru google chrome dev tools) it used internally monaco-editor, but also it has files structure navigation, tabs and so on, so its more similar to https://vscode.dev, I have tried found source code of this site, but I cannot, does it private? Does codesandbox write its own separate code for managing tabs and file structure?

P.S. I talking mostly about frontend related part of it, not the backend.

Comment: Try the Github repository of Microsoft on Github. Maybe the code is there. Note also: questions for libraries and other external resources etc. are not valid for Stackoverflow. So expect your question to be closed.